# Webdriver without window popup

Tags: python, selenium, webdriver, video-streaming, selenium-chromedriver

I'm currently writinng a script to interact with a live stream, mainly taking `screenshots`.

I'm using `Selenium Webdriver` for Python to open `Chromedriver` and go from there.

However, I want to build this behavior into a bigger program and hide the whole process of opening `chromedriver`, waiting for the stream to load and then taking a screenshot, so the user only gets the screenshot once it's done.

From what I've found online,  it's not possible to hide the command-line console within my script with something like setVisible and I'm okay with the console showing up, but I really have to hide the website popup, so the screenshot will be taken in the background.

Is it possible to do so in Python/Selenium or do I have to switch to another language?

Comment: So you want a *"headless"* test?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a headless browser like htmlunit to run your tests without a browser popup: https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/htmlunit-driver

Comment: Didn't know it's called a headless browser, thanks for the link

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a script with vb or python which will close the popups on the basis of their titles.

Even you can minimise them also.
Code in vb
Set wshShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")

Do 
    ret = wshShell.AppActivate("title of the popup") 
    If ret = True Then 
        wshShell.SendKeys "%N" 
        Exit Do 
    End If 
    WScript.Sleep 500 
Loop

Comment: Minimizing isn't what I'm looking for, I need the window to be completely invisible. Also, doesn't closing the popups imply that I can't work with them anymore? I still need to take screenshots with the invisible browser windows.

Comment: Please correct if i got you wrong But htmlunit driver is headless means there would not be a UI so you would not get screenshot.

Comment: Guess I shouldn't call it a screenshot, but I do need a picture of a website's content without showing the website on the screen.

Comment: Yes you can get the content for sure with headless driver

Comment: @Hillburn You cannot take any picture of the website's content using a headless browser as obbiously the browser will be headless, it won't render the content, there will be no content to take a picture of.